# Is there a way to get the resultCode onActivityResult() when i share something to facebook without using FaceBook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook

So, I've created an share button on my application for twitter and facebook, and I need to know if it was shared or canceled.
On twitter I get the correct resultCode, but on facebook I don't. Is there a way to get the correct result code from facebook without using the facebookSDK?

Here's my default code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(LOG, "OK");
            Log.d(LOG, "CODE = " + resultCode);
            //do something on google analytics

        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.d(LOG, "NOT OK");
            Log.d(LOG, "CODE = " + resultCode);
            Log.d(LOG, data == null ? "null" : data.getDataString());
            //do something on google analytics
        }
    }
}
```

thanks 
btw its my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: You told that Twitter works for you..
For me, Twitter share always returns RESULT_CANCELED

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Start your intent like this:

`startActivityForResult(intent, 1);` //instead of startActivity(intent)

And retrieve the requestCode and resultCode by overriding onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            //intent 1 = successful (Facebook)
        } else{
             failed or canceled
        }

    }
}
```